# How to jerry-rig a menu bar in Vaadin Flow version 12

Tags: vaadin, menubar, vaadin-flow

Per [this forum thread](https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/17167715/17370585), a proper menubar widget is promised for Vaadin Flow [in version 14](https://vaadin.com/roadmap) for June 2019 next year, according to the [*Components* page](https://vaadin.com/docs/flow/migration/5-components.html) in the manual.

Until then, that page suggests a menu bar can be jerry-rigged in version 12 using `Select` and `ContextMenu`.

> MenuBar
>
> Planned for Vaadin 14. Can be made currently by combining Select (V12) and ContextMenu (V12)

(a) I cannot find either `Select` or `ContextMenu` in the [version 12 JavaDoc](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/12.0.0.alpha5/overview-summary.html).

(b) Has anyone an example implementation to share?

Comment: Platform version 12 is under construction and will be released in the beginning of December, the JavaDocs of these components, etc. are to arrive by then. The release schedule is here: https://vaadin.com/roadmap

Answer (score 1):

`ContextMenu` is a transitive dependency in at least *12.0.0.beta1*

Some very basic example (Groovy 2.5):

```
def fileMenu
content.add(
        fileMenu = new Div(new Text("File")).tap{
            style.set('cursor', 'pointer')
        },
)
new ContextMenu(fileMenu).tap{
    openOnClick = true // allows opening with a left-click
    addItem("Open", {println "open"})
    addItem("Save", {println "save"})
}
```

Given the crude nature of that and the relative ease to add something from webcomponents.org you might be better off with something else.  Yet there seems to be just one classic menu bar (https://www.webcomponents.org/element/wiredjs/wired-menu-bar) for mocking UIs.